# Web search engine that fully supports boolean operators

Tags: search-engine, hosted, web

I just realized that Google doesn't support full boolean logic, in particular no parenthesis operator, [as described here](https://www.quora.com/Google-does-not-support-full-Boolean-logic-no-parenthesis-operator-Does-that-mean-a-OR-b-c-OR-d-will-always-yield-search-result-that-includes-b-c-because-Google-recognizes-it-as-a-OR-b-AND-c-OR-d).

Is there any web search engine which does have a full Boolean logic support?

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly DuckDuckGo does. https://brettterpstra.com/2019/03/07/the-ultimate-guide-to-duckduckgo/ I have not tried it.